# Como concatenar tag html em php?

Tags: php, html, string, html-tags

```
$t ='<span style=\"color:#FF0000;\"> ';
$t. "texto '</span>' ";
echo $t;
```

O código acima não funciona, nada é impresso. 
Acredito que o problema é no fechamento da `tag` **`span`**.

Como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Tem alguns erros, mas, o básico seria:

```
$t ='<span style="color:#FF0000;"> ';
$t .= "texto </span> ";
echo $t;
```

[Exemplo - IDEONE](http://ideone.com/p9gZxE)

Comment: Obrigado Virgilio. deu certo agora.